# Three js Progress loading OBJMTLLoader

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am wanting a method to get the loading progress of .obj and .mtl file in three.js.

In previous version (as r53) I do that with:

```
loader = new THREE.OBJMTLLoader();

loader.addEventListener('progress', function ( item ){
    console.log( item.loaded, item.total, item );
    });
```

but now, using version r67 I can´t do that whith this code.

I try with:

```
var loader = new THREE.OBJMTLLoader();  

loader.load( 'obj/inicial/modelo.obj', 'obj/inicial/modelo.mtl', function(object){
    scene.add( object );
    }, function(item){
        console.log(item);
        });
```

but it doesn´t works.

I searched google but have not found anything about. Can someone help me?

Thans in advance.

Comment: Take a look at the [LoadingManager](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Loaders/LoadingManager) class. There is an example on the docs page.

Comment: I've also tried that method, but I do not get any data from the console.

Comment: it seems that the LoadingManager class gives progress of multiple loaders, not progress of each loader/file. As in, the progress event is fired when each file is fully loaded.

Comment: Hmm, It seems that the OBJMTLLoader class has changed quite a bit. I can confirm that the progress and error event functions passed to the constructor of OBJMTLLoader do not fire. It seems the class was changed quite a bit on 12 Sep 2013. https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/commit/21515188fd613a71f3d76199b7ae60857f168d25 . You may be better off loading them separately or creating your own class to load them together.

Comment: For the record, I made a pull request to pass onProgress and onError callbacks, hopefully it will be merged at some point. https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/5423

Answer (score 0):

Both LoadingManager and onProgress callbacks should/will be available in dev and in master soon, hopefully.

For onProgress, onError in OBJMTLLoader
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/5423

For LoadingManager support
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/5463

Comment: I hope the callbacks be available soon. In my particular case loaded objs have much more size which I would like, and loading procsess is very slow, ans in this process the feelings of the users are that the application has been "hung". Regards.

Answer (score 0):

The OBJMTLLoader class is deprecated, instead the latest three.js (r78) uses MTLLoader plus OBJLoader, codes are something like below:

```js
var onProgress = function ( xhr ) {
    if ( xhr.lengthComputable ) {
        var percentComplete = xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100;
        console.log( Math.round(percentComplete, 2) + '% downloaded' );
    }
};

var onError = function ( xhr ) { };

THREE.Loader.Handlers.add( /\.dds$/i, new THREE.DDSLoader() );

var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
mtlLoader.setPath( 'obj/male02/' );
mtlLoader.load( 'male02_dds.mtl', function( materials ) {

    materials.preload();

    var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
    objLoader.setMaterials( materials );
    objLoader.setPath( 'obj/male02/' );
    objLoader.load( 'male02.obj', function ( object ) {

        object.position.y = - 95;
        scene.add( object );

    }, onProgress, onError );

});
```